# Starting point for backward selection in polynomial linear models in R

Tags: r, linear-model, mgcv, lm, stepwise-regression

I am reading [Generalized Additive Models by Simon N. Wood](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood). I do not have a very strong formal background in maths and statistics, so this question might be too trivial. However, I am well versed in R.

I just finished the first chapter of Simple Linear Models and started with the exercise to grasp things well. In one of the question's author used **Rubber-dataset** from `library(MASS)` to model the *loss* as a $3^{rd}$ order polynomial function of *tens* and *hard*. Below is the dataset,

```
   loss  hard tens
1  372   45   162
2  206   55   233
3  175   61   232
4  154   66   231
5  136   71   231
6  112   71   237
```

After that, he used `lm()` to model the equation and then made a backward selection based on the t-statistic's p-values to identify the appropriate model. Here's how he models the formula

```
lm(loss˜hard+tens+I(hard*tens)+I(hardˆ2)+I(tensˆ2)+ I(hardˆ2*tens)+I(tensˆ2*hard)+I(tensˆ3)+I(hardˆ3),Rubber)
```

Now for a $3^{rd}$ order polynomial we will model $$y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}*X_{i}^{3} + \beta_{2}*X_{i}^{2} + \beta_{3}*X_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$$

As per our current dataset, we have to model,

$$loss = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}*(tens+hard)_{i}^{3} + \beta_{2}*(tens+hard)_{i}^{2} + \beta_{3}*(tens+hard)_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$$

which can be simplified to (after removing $\beta_{j}$ and $\epsilon_{i}$) (input for `lm()`),
$$loss = (tens+hard)_{i}^{3} + (tens+hard)_{i}^{2} + (tens+hard)_{i}$$

Which can be further simplified for **lm()**,
$$
hard^{3}+hard^{2}+hard+tens^{3}+tens^{2}+tens+3*hard^{2}*tens+ 3*tens^{2}*hard + 2*hard*tens
$$

then, I expect the **lm()** input to be as

```
lm(loss˜hard+tens+I(2*hard*tens)+I(hardˆ2)+I(tensˆ2)+ I(3*hardˆ2*tens)+I(3*tensˆ2*hard)+I(tensˆ3)+I(hardˆ3),Rubber)
```

I don't understand why the author does not use coefficients *2* and *3* while making the equation for **lm()**. Why have they used `I(hard*tens) + I(hardˆ2*tens)+I(tensˆ2*hard)`  not `(2*hard*tens) + I(3*hardˆ2*tens)+I(3*tensˆ2*hard)`?

I would really appreciate any help or intuition behind modeling this. Thanks.

---

I am adding the question just in case,

*The MASS library contains a data frame Rubber on the wear of tire rubber. The
response loss measures rubber loss in grams per hour. The predictors are
tens, a measure of the tensile strength of the rubber with units of kg −2,
and hard, the hardness of the rubber in Shore § units. Modeling interest focuses
on predicting wear from hardness and tensile strength.
(a) Starting with a model in which loss is a polynomial function of tens and
hard, with all terms up to 3rd order present, perform backward model se-
lection, based on hypothesis testing, to select an appropriate model for these
data.*

Comment: What justifies ignoring the coefficients and error term?  When you dropped those, you departed from describing a model.  That appears to be more of an error than a simplification. The resulting algebra is not helpful for understanding that model.

Comment: I dropped the coefficients and error terms because they are automatically calculated by the [lm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm). I will edit the question and add why I removed them. However, I am interested in why we do not include coefficients 3 and 2.

Comment: @PriyanshSrivastava The binomial coefficients are absorbed into the estimates of $\beta$.  The model is linear in the parameters, so the scale of the variables just changes the estimate and not the model.

Comment: The "and" in the question has its usual English meaning; it does not intend you to use the sum of `tens` and `hard` as the explanatory variable.  To illustrate, here is a basic one-line solution to the question: `with(Rubber,  stepAIC(lm(loss ~ poly(tens, hard, degree = 3)), direction = "backward"))`.